# How to have 2 servers, different paths with same domain?

Tags: apache2, server, webserver

Looking for some advice on the following:

I'm wanting to have two servers with same domain. Not looking to have subdomains.

Domain: https://example.com

Server A: https://example.com/games/abcs13343/results

Server B: https://example.com/blogs/games-blog-3

Is this achievable through doing a proxy reverse on Server A or is there a better way of doing something like this without subdomains?

Comment: You cannot have two servers with the same domain name without very special tricks. You can proxy a path from Server A to Server B very easily. Server B would be represent a sub portion of the domain name space but would not have a different server name (usually an IP address or localhost).

Comment: @JohnHanley - That what it would be, Server B would just be an IP address for the time being. 

So would it have to be a proxy from Server A to Server B?

Comment: The following question can give you a hint on how to do it: https://serverfault.com/questions/429122/apache-virtualhost-proxy-with-a-subdirectory

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran - Would this work if the `/blogs` isn't an actual sub directory on the server and is just a route in the web application?

Comment: yes it should work. You can have /blogs point to a different server, or even a different port inside your own server, using Apache as the proxy

Comment: Why don't you want subdomains? They are meant for situations exactly like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have your 2 servers, Server A and Server B with IP_A, IP_B respectively.

The HTTP/HTTPS requests come through ports and using a basic router only ports can be forwarded to each of your 2 local server IPs.

You can use 1 of your 2 servers to act as a proxy to the other server.

Firstly forward port 80 & 443 to the server A using its ip IPA.

Let the server with ip IPA, channel the requests to the other server(s) based on the requested URL.

Depending on what Server Software you use you need to follow different approaches.

In apache for port 80 you will need to edit your configuration file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Add the lines at the end of `<VirtualHost *.80>`

```
<VirtualHost *.80>

....

RewriteRule ^/games/?(.*)$ http://{IPB}/games/$1 [P,L] 
ProxyPassReverse /games http://{IPB}/games

RewriteRule ^/blogs/?(.*)$ http://{IPB}/blogs/$1 [P,L] 
ProxyPassReverse /blogs http://{IPB}/blogs

    
</VirtualHost>
```

In each case, we added the `ProxyPassReverse` directive to ensure that any redirects issued by the backend are correctly passed on to the client.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this achievable through doing a proxy reverse on Server A or is
> there a better way of doing something like this without subdomains?

Yes - this is a very common use case for a reverse proxy server.

I disagree slightly with @Thanasis answer) in as much as the ideal way to do this with Apache is NOT RewriteRules, rather it is ProxyPass rules.   (Indeed this is the whole purpose of [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) in Apache).

The idea is in your Virtualhost to ensure mod_proxy is enabled (eg with a2enmod proxy to enable this) and then add

```
ProxyPass "/blogs" "https://serverb.domain"
ProxyPassReverse "/blogs" "https://serverb.domain"
```

If this is "to much", you can always look at using someone like Cloudflare to do it for you.

Comment: Use of the [P] flag ( my RewriteRule) causes the request to be handled by mod_proxy, and handled via a proxy request. The advantage in using mod_rewrite is that you get more control for mapping requests. But you are right somewhere in the apache documentation ( https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p )it states that it is better to use ProxyPass directly as it handles better the persistent connections.